# how to add progress bar on loading in Firebase recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I am builiding a app the fetchs the data from firebase using firebase recycler adapter i need to implement the progress in that recyler view.

i am unable to get how to load a particular amount of data at a time for example load 3 items and show progress bar and then load other items.
And also show progress bar when the items are loading in the start

this is the code where data is being fetched

```
final ProgressBar p1=(ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.StreetRecyclerProgress);
                final LinearLayout likeLayout=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Likee);
                MainArea.viewPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background);
                myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street");
                myRef1.keepSynced(true);
                myRef1.orderByKey();
                rView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.StreetRecyclerView);
                rView.hasFixedSize();
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {

                    @Override
                    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
                        LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(getActivity()) {

                            private static final float SPEED = 300f;// Change this value (default=25f)

                            @Override
                            protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                                return SPEED / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                            }

                        };
                        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
                        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
                    }

                };
                rView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StreetDataFetcher, Street_food.StreetViewHolder>(
                        StreetDataFetcher.class,
                        R.layout.card_recycler_view,
                        Street_food.StreetViewHolder.class,
                        myRef1
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder( Street_food.StreetViewHolder viewHolder, StreetDataFetcher model, final int position ) {
                        //p1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getVideoName());
                        viewHolder.setShortDesc(model.getShort_Desc());
                        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUserName());
                        viewHolder.setDate(model.getDateTime());
                        viewHolder.setVideoPath(model.getVideoPath());
                        viewHolder.setProfile(model.getProfileImage());
                        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick( View v ) {
                                final String mref;
                                mref=FBRA.getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim();
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mref.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),StreetVideoView.class);
                                i.putExtra("position",mref);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }
                        });
                        viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.Likee).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick( View v ) {
                                ImageView a;
                                a=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.likeImage);
                                a.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_on);
                                final String mref;
                                mref=FBRA.getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim();
                                final DatabaseReference myyRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street").child(mref).child("Likes");
                                myyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {
                                        Integer i=Integer.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                        int ii=i+1;
                                        String like_value= String.valueOf(ii);
                                        myyRef.setValue(like_value);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError ) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                rView.setAdapter(FBRA);
```

**things i need in this code is the progress bar should show when recycler view is fetching/ loading data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting progress bar visibility to VISIBLE and INVISIBLE do the trick. I have done this in a fragment like this

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        DiseaseFragment.show_progress();

                if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                    DiseaseFragment.Hide_no_content_message();
        DiseaseFragment.hide_progress();
                    // data is found
                }
                else{

                   /* If no data found do this */
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                  @Override
                                                  public void run() {
                                                      DiseaseFragment.hide_progress();

                                                  }
                                              },3000);}}
```

Called a static function to set the Visibility of progress bar to VISIBLE/INVISIBLE.
where 3000 is the millisecond which is equal to 3 second and if no data found , wait for 3 seconds and hide the progressbar

Answer (score 0):

In your main Fragment you can use static methods like,

```
 public static void enableThem() {
             mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             mTextNoPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public static void disableThem() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTextNoPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

While in your recycler adapter you can overide the `onDataChanged()` method and add instantiate it.

```
@Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        MainFragment.disableThem();
    }
```